# Laravel Auth::attempt() not actually login

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, eloquent

When I am taking an attempt to login it just redirecting to "admin" page with any value. I did all the possible try found in google. But still not having luck. I am badly in need of help. My code is given below :

Controller: LoginController.php

```
<?php 

class LoginController extends BaseController {


    public function doLogin()
    {

        $rules = ['username'=>'required','password'=>'required'];

        $credentials = array(
          'username' => Input::get('username'),
          'password' => Input::get('password')
        );


        $validation = Validator::make($credentials, $rules);

        if($validation->fails()){

            return Redirect::back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation);

        }
        else{

            Auth::attempt($credentials);
            return Redirect::intended('admin');
        }

    }

    public function doLogOut()
    {
        Auth::logout();

        return Redirect::to('/login');
    }

}
```

Model: User.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

UserTableSeeder:

```
<?php

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $vader = DB::table('users')->insert([
                'username'   => 'admin',
                'password'   => Hash::make('admin'),
                'created_at' => new DateTime(),
                'updated_at' => new DateTime()
            ]);
    }

}
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('login','LoginController@doLogIn');
```

Comment: Post your Users table DESC please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at these lines:

```
else {
    Auth::attempt($credentials);
    return Redirect::intended('admin');
}
```

What you're doing in this snippet is

1. You try to log the user in.
2. Then you redirect, regardless of whether it worked or not.

If you want to make sure the user is actually logged in, you should wrap the attempt within an if clause.